# What returns a DAO?

Tags: design-patterns, dao

Lets suppose that I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar` with each respective `DAO`.

Lets say that a `foo` has many `bars`.

So the method that returns the `bars` of a `foo` where should it go?

```
class FooDAO
  def bars_from_foo(foo)
    # return the bars of that foo
  end
end

class BarDAO
  def bars_from_foo(foo)
    # returns the bars of that foo
  end
end
```

My doubt is, does `FooDAO` only return `foo` objects? Or does `FooDAO` only include the methods that a `foo` will need?

In my opinion, I choose the first one: `FooDAO` only returns `foo` objects. Because, the method could be used from another class, that has nothing in common with the other `DAO`. I can't think in an example right now.

I would like to read some opinions from experts.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches:

- The fact that a `foo` has many `bars` can actually be modeled in your `Foo` class: `foo.get_bars()` would return the `bars`. `FooDAO` would then be responsible for making sure that this works properly, either by fetching the `bars` at instantiation time or by using lazy-loading.
- The fact that a `bar` has a corresponding `foo` can be viewed as a search criterion for `bar`. `BarDAO` would then have a `find_bars_by_foo_id(foo_id)` or `find_bars_by_foo(foo)`. (This is pretty similar to your second possibility; the key is to think about it the right way.) Alternatively, it would have a `find_bars(criteria)`, where `criteria` can have settings such as the `foo_id` to use.

Which approach is most appropriate will depend on the semantics of the two classes and of the relationship between them.

Comment: Of course, the first approach is right. The `Foo` class has the method `get_bars()`. Because the idea of using `DAO` is to avoid implementing 'database' code in your model, it will call a `DAO` method. But the question is, where is this method?

Comment: @Quarktum: `get_bars()` should *not* involve a database call, since that makes it impossible to use a `foo` in a non-database context (such as in a unit-test, or serialized over a network interface, or whatnot). Instead, as I said, `FooDAO` is responsible for ensuring that `foo.get_bars()` works, either by pre-fetching the `bars` or by setting `bars` to a lazy-loaded collection that performs a database call the first time it is inspected. (That said, `FooDAO` can delegate to `BarDAO`, if convenient. That's just an implementation detail, not part of the design pattern.)